# Why is this makefile not creating an executable with MinGW?

Tags: makefile, mingw

I am trying out MinGW on windows. I've been able to use GCC to create a executable from a C source file.

main.c is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int this_is_a_number;

    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &this_is_a_number);
    printf("You entered: %d", this_is_a_number);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

the makefile has this:

```
cProj: main.c
    gcc -o cProj main.c
```

When I run `make` from a powershell, I get this:

```
PS C:\Projects\cProj> make
Target 'cProj' is up to date
PS C:\Projects\cProj>
```

However, after I run `make`, there is no executable in the directory.

```
PS C:\Projects\cProj> ls


    Directory: C:\Projects\cProj


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---          4/7/2015  10:33 PM        207 main.c
-a---          5/2/2015   8:35 PM         35 makefile
```

As you can see, there are no errors with the makefile. At least not that I can see. The gcc compiler does work with the parameters that are passed to it. when I run `gcc -o cProj main.c`, it creates an executable without nay problem.

I know the makefile that I have is very explicit and is not a good makefile for an actual project. I'm just trying to get make to work on my windows machine.

What am I doing wrong?

The version of make that I have (from MinGW) is Digital Mars Make version 5.06.

GCC is version 4.8.1.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would expect a MinGW installation to have GNU make, not a make form Digital Mars (not that I have any reason to think that's responsible for whatever problem you're having).

Comment: that might be it.... when I run mingw32-make.exe it works!

Comment: I wonder if the Digital Mars Make is there because I had downloaded D some time ago.

Comment: I'm sure you're right that you got Digital Mars `make` with D - I wonder why it doesn't process the simple makefile the same way as GNU make since there doesn't seem to be anything unusual about the makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue was that I was using the wrong make.

when I execute the make program that actually came with MinGW, then the process all works.

```
c:\Projects\cProj> mingw32-make.exe
```

That works.

Answer (score 0):

To make Digital Mars Make work, just append a terminating end-of-line to your makefile.